# How to use awscli to set a non-english ec2's name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, aws-cli

I try to use awscli to set up a new name for my ec2 instances:

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resources i-891053a1 --tags "Key=Name,Value=我的主機"
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Eveything is ok, when I set the name in English, but non English not work. I have no idea how to do that. Anyone do it successfully ?

Comment: What version of awscli are you using?  Try "aws --version" to find out.

Comment: It is aws-cli/1.2.13 Python/2.7.6 Darwin/13.1.0

Comment: I update it to 'aws-cli/1.3.1 Python/2.7.6 Darwin/13.1.0', but it is still broken.

Comment: It would appear that the client does not support anything other than ASCII. You could try the aws java based cli tools.

Comment: This is a bug in the AWS CLI.  I've filed https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/711 to track this.

Comment: @jamesls it works. I have tried it last week.